# How to declare a generic function type? TS2315: Type is not generic

Tags: typescript, oop

I have this implementation of the Observer Pattern:

```
type EventHandler = <T extends Event>(event: T) => void;

interface Subscriber<T> {
    event: EventEnum;
    callback: EventHandler<T>;
}
```

I want to have this `Subscriber` interface so that I can declare, for example:

```
interface EventEmitter {
    Xsubscribers: Array<Subscriber<EventX>>;
    Ysubscribers: Array<Subscriber<EventY>>
    addEventXListener: (callback: EventHandler<EventX>) => void;
    addEventYListener: (callback: EventHandler<EventY>) => void;
}
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

> error TS2315: Type 'EventHandler' is not generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the generic before the `=`:

```
type EventHandler<T extends Event> = (event: T) => void;

interface Subscriber<T extends Event> {
    // event: EventEnum;
    callback: EventHandler<T>;
}
type EventY = Event;
type EventX = Event;

interface EventEmitter {
    Xsubscribers: Array<Subscriber<EventX>>;
    Ysubscribers: Array<Subscriber<EventY>>
    addEventXListener: (callback: EventHandler<EventX>) => void;
    addEventYListener: (callback: EventHandler<EventY>) => void;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAEgQ0QEwDYQE4A8AKlBAB7BKYDOsCyAfFALxQAUE9wAXFEQJQsmcAPYBLTAG4AsACg5Y5PgBmaAMbQAygFcARtTV4xu-MVIUqteEmBMA3nKhOoAehekuva8hiJtAWxlZZyg1NGxsXXUAay8udCxcQiIGIIBfOVBIOhsATRYc5CCs6G9gAA0CsqCFJTxVDULgGH8xYEo8KAdg53LqPQMjEzxqXgBBPDw0EAIdfUNjUzLyhlTHZ1z++aH8UagJqZm5wcXCMtzV9ac0TExlgBkxakpEfF42MIiotVimhJwllwVoJmMJxFIrlAbncuLlHs8kG92J9IjE4jZ-kkCOcGCCwRJ0kA)

Comment: Ahhh, I knew it had something to do with the type alias declaration. Message was too cryptic. Do you know what the difference with `type EventHandler = <T extends Event>(event: T) => void;` is?

Comment: The difference is that `type EventHandler = <T extends Event>(event: T) => void;` makes a generic function signature rather than a generic type.

Comment: I get it. So, in one case the type argument should be passed when you call the function and in the other, when you declare another type.